# Using a different font in overpic

Tags: captions, memoir, overpic

I'm using the `overpic` package in the `memoir` class to include figures and superimpose text on them.  Is there a simple way to tell overpic to use a different font than the main font of my text?  (I still want the figure captions to be in the main font, though.)

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{fouriernc} % use the Arev font
\usepackage{overpic} % use the overpic package

% caption images outside the figure environment
\newfixedcaption{\figcaption}{figure} \captionnamefont{\normalfont} \captiontitlefont{\normalfont}

\begin{document}

This is the font of my main text.

\begin{center}
\begin{overpic}[width=0.5\textwidth]{./myfig.pdf}
\put(10, 10){This should be a different font}
\end{overpic}
\figcaption{This should be the same font as my main text.}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just say, for instance, `\put(10,10){\sffamily This is in the sans serif font}`; edit your question if this isn't what you have in mind.

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind, but is there a way to define a macro so that every `\put` command in `overpic` automatically switches to some font?  (So that I don't need to write something like `\sffamily` in every `\put` in the document...)  Thanks!

Comment: `\usepackage{etoolbox}` and then `\AtBeginEnvironment{overpic}{\sffamily}` should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could redefine `\put` to insert `\sffamily` (or whichever font selection) automatically by inserting the following in your document preamble:

```
\let\oldput\put
\def\put(#1,#2)#3{%
  \oldput(#1,#2){\sffamily #3}%
}
```

Here's a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\let\oldput\put
\def\put(#1,#2)#3{%
  \oldput(#1,#2){\sffamily #3}%
}
\usepackage{fouriernc} % use the Arev font
\usepackage{overpic} % use the overpic package

% caption images outside the figure environment
\newfixedcaption{\figcaption}{figure} \captionnamefont{\normalfont} \captiontitlefont{\normalfont}

\begin{document}

This is the font of my main text.

\begin{center}
\begin{overpic}[width=0.5\textwidth]{tiger.pdf}
\put(10, 10){This should be a different font}
\end{overpic}
\figcaption{This should be the same font as my main text.}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!  In my actual document, though, most of the text in `\put`s is actually in math mode (inside `$`s), so the `sffamily` font doesn't help distinguish it...  Is there another font I can use with a different math mode font than `Arev`?

Comment: @jamaicanworm: Do you have a variety of serif and sans-serif math fonts going on in your document? If not, the [`sfmath` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/sfmath) (or [`sansmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sansmath)) might be of help.

Comment: I added `\usepackage{sansmath}` to the top of the document, and replaced `\sffamily` with `\sansmath`, and it's working great now!