# Missing symbols in the sansmath package

Tags: fonts, sans-serif

When using the [`sansmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sansmath) package with the `Arev` font, symbols like `+` and `=` fail to appear in the compiled document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc} % use the Arev font
\usepackage{sansmath}
\begin{document}
You can see this $+$ and this $=$.
But you can't see \sansmath this $+$ and this $=$.
\end{document}
```

If, however, I switch the order of `\usepackage` to include `sansmath` first and *then* `fouriernc`, for some reason you now *can* see the symbols, but I get two errors...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepackage{fouriernc} % use the Arev font
\begin{document}
You can see this $+$ and this $=$.
Now you can see \sansmath this $+$ and this $=$, but there are 2 errors.
\end{document}
```

> ! LaTeX Error: Command `\mathrm' already defined.
>
> ! LaTeX Error: Command `\mathrm' already defined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package `fouriernc` doesn't use Arev fonts, but rather NewCentury Schoolbook and a modified version of the Fourier math fonts.

These fonts have different symbol positions and so they define `+` and `=` differently from normal: the normal mathcode of `+` is `"202B` (in hexadecimal form), while `fouriernc` uses `"2280`.

These cryptic codes say: `+` is an operation symbol (first digit 2), which comes from math family 0 (in the standard setting) or 2 (in the `fouriernc` settings). The symbol lives in font position `"2B` (standard setting) or `"80` (`fouriernc`).

The package `sansmath` expects standard codes; in family 2 it uses `cmsy10` which in position `"80` has nothing (it's a seven bit font).

So the two packages are completely incompatible.

Comment: Thanks, but then do you have an alternative to the answer to my question here?  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44926/9757  (the comments are relevant).  Is there another font/package that will change my Fourier math fonts?

Comment: The alternatives are: not using math in captions or not using a sans serif font in captions. Sorry: reverting all the math codes when switching to `\sansmath` is a job that nobody would undertake.

Comment: I'm fine with not using a sans serif font; the original question was to just have the font in my `overpic` captions be different from my main font (including in math mode).  Is there another (non-sans-serif) solution for this?

Comment: Two different serif fonts are quite difficult to combine, but even if they existed, the problem would be just the same: if the main font changes the math codes, also the other font should use the same conventions (or the big work of doing a reversal each time one switches font family should be carried out).

Comment: Is it possible to switch to something like the default LaTeX font for a short section of text with a basic command (a la `\sffamily`, but for switching fonts instead of serifs)?

Comment: It's theoretically possible: take the *huge* default math symbol table and keep it somewhere to be called when you want `\sansmath`. Practical? No, sorry. This table is built in a large number of steps and keeping track of it is a herculean task.

Comment: Okay.  For this particular issue, I've established a workaround where I write `\unsansmath $+$ \sansmath $remaining maths$`.  Thank you for your help--you went above and beyond answering this question!