# Conflict between sansmath and fixmath?

Tags: math-mode, sans-serif

My question may be a duplicate of [Missing symbols in the sansmath package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45187/missing-symbols-in-the-sansmath-package), but I don't know. I need to use a sans font for math and I generally load the `fixmath` package (although I am not sure why). Apparently using `fixmath` along with `sansmath` doesn't work so well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixmath}
% \DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{25}
\usepackage{sansmath}

\begin{document}
\sansmath\sffamily $\pi$
\end{document}
```

What is happening?

Comment: first rule of latex preambles: if you don't know what a package is doing, don't load it:-)  fixmath documents that it is unlikley to work with anything other than the default cm math font setup.....

Answer (score 1):

Both `unicode-math` and `isomath` define sans-serif Greek alphabets.

The `unicode-math` package has several sans-serif math alphabets, but of these, only `\mathbfsfit` and `\mathbfsfup` contain lowercase Greek letters in Unicode.  You can also declare a new math alphabet with `\setmathfontface` if you need normal-weight Greek sans-serif letters.

The `isomath` package adds the alphabets `\mathsfit` for italic sans-serif and `\mathsfbfit` for bold italic sans serif.  It uses legacy eight-bit font encodings, but as a result, it is compatible with PDFLaTeX.  You would want to use a sans-serif font with the OML encoding, but it is also possible to use LGR.

Finally, you can define a new math symbol such as `\sfuppi` that inserts a sans-serif upright π from your font of choice.  The exact method will depend on which font you use and how it is encoded.